# MacOs Launching android command from Terminal, it responds only with usage informations

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

I installed Android Studio on my iMac (MacOs Sierra) and the installation process has installed for me also the Android SDK. I've added the environment paths to tools and tools/bin folders.

Now, If I use Android Studio and I launch the SDK manager Window by the appropriate menu item, all works fine.

When I instead launch the "android" command from the terminal, nothing happen.

The command responds with only usage information about the command.

It also informs me that "android" command is deprecated and it suggests to use sdkmanager instead. I've used but also this command responds with only usage information. Same behavior with "android avd" or "avdmanager" commands

When I use this commands in windows machine, it opens the sdk manager window and the "android virtual device" window respectively.

What I'm in wrong?

Below is the terminal response.

---

The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

---

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk